# Upgrading from jQueryUI 1.8.4 to 1.8.5 breaks code

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using a slider gallery script that was developed with an older version of jQueryUI and I found that upgrading it from 1.8.4 to 1.8.5 breaks it somewhere. I can't seem to find what the offending part is and after reading the changelog from 1.8.4 to 1.8.5 (as well as comparing the source), I can't seem to find what's wrong.

I also looked into the jQuery migration tool, but that didn't help.

Is there any validation tool for jQueryUI that I could use to see what exactly is wrong?

I'm happy to post the code here as well of course, if somebody can take a look at it.

Thanks!

EDIT: No errors in the console.

Comment: I should've mentioned - there were no errors in the console (or I'm not using it right). Thanks.

Comment: what happens to you slider gallery, have you checked other possible error sources? (database, [...])

Comment: The gallery simply doesn't appear. It's not coming from a DB, just simple JPEGs on disk. Everything is client-side. The error I do get is that the slider object is not created (because JS fails to call some methods on it)

Comment: Try to check the constructor/initialized function for the gallery plugin for some clues.

Comment: I went through all the code (there isn't that much of it) and I just can't seem to find a spot where it would fail. I compared jQueryUI 1.8.4 to 1.8.5 code to check for deprecated/removed functions and nothing jumps out at me either.

Comment: Does it break in all browsers?

Comment: Yes, it breaks in all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, for some reason in 1.8.4 this works:

```
var $slider = $('#slider');
```

However, it should be:

```
var $slider = $('#slider').slider();
```